# Unable to read video in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to read video file, but its throwing error.
The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Mat inputVideo;
    Mat frame;
    Mat HSV;
    Mat tracking;
    char checkKey;
    VideoCapture capture;
    capture.open("video/input.mp4");
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480);      
    namedWindow("Original Video", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    while(1){
        capture.read(inputVideo);
        if (!inputVideo.empty())
        {
            imshow("Original Video",inputVideo);

        }
        waitKey(20);

    }
    return 0;
 }
```

On running this code, the error I am getting is:

> Unable to stop the stream: Inappropriate ioctl for device
>
> (video_reading:3459): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set:
>   assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
>
> I tried looking for solutions, but i did not get it. Can some one help me in solving this error.

Comment: May be ffmpeg error. Try building it again using cmake

Comment: @Ran did you build `opencv` with Gstreamer?

Comment: I dont know what is gstreamer. I had build opencv using following command        cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 -D WITH_CUDA=ON -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 -D WITH_CUBLAS=1 ..

Answer (score 0):

I made little changes in your code. Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Mat inputVideo;
    Mat frame;
    Mat HSV;
    Mat tracking;
    char checkKey;
    VideoCapture capture;
    capture.open("video/input.mp4");
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
    namedWindow("Original Video", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    while (1) {
        capture >> inputVideo;
        if (inputVideo.empty())
            break;
        imshow("Original Video", inputVideo);
        waitKey(1);
    }
    capture.release();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this does not solve the problem, it may still give you the same error

Comment: @jazz yeah as Anirudh was saying, I am getting the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: Ok. Then you have to again build it with cmake. For my system, it worked.

Comment: I build again using cmake, now showing #include <opencv/highgui.h> no such file or directory.